# Starting a native daemon in init.rc with su rights on Android Oreo

Tags: android, kernel, root, daemon, android-8.0-oreo

I need to start a simple daemon at boot in Android Oreo AOSP with su rights.

I've set SE Linux to permissive changing kernel bootargs settings, compiled the daemon and put the executable in /system/xbin , added service definition in init.rc but still get:

avc : denied { transition }

If the daemon is launched by shell ( with su privileges) it works without problems.

I've followed the solution proposed by many users here on stackoverflow without results.

Any help or suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Init will need at least an SELinux context to transition the process to. I am afraid you will have to define one even when running in permissive mode.

Add the following to your `file_contexts`

```
/system/xbin/<my-service>    u:object_r:<some-context>:s0
```

---

**EDIT**: It might suffice to add a `seclabel` attribute to your service configuration in `init.rc` [(see init)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md).

```
service my-service /system/xbin/my-service
    [...]
    seclabel u:r:su:s0
```